# delete certain rows when using merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have recently come across merge statements which are very handy but I'm unsure about how to delete certain records.

In my example say my current table has the following records. Then I need to re-import the data for the account ABC. In my merge statement I have an update when matched & then when not matched by the target it inserts the data. This works fine. What I can't work out though is how to delete data. The second table below shows the data I want to re-import, so I want my delete query to ignore any rows that don't have the date 2021-03-01 and where the account is not equal to ABC. I.e. only delete the row where the account is ABC with the date 2021-03-01 and has the id AM74, is that possible?

```
date         account    id     value
2021-03-01   ABC        AM74   0.345
2021-03-01   ABC        AM91   0.354
2021-03-01   ABC        AC32   0.276
2021-03-01   ABC        AD12   0.445
2021-03-01   DEF        AC32   0.276
2021-03-01   DEF        AD12   0.445

**data to be re-imported**

date         account    id     value    
2021-03-01   ABC        AM91   0.354
2021-03-01   ABC        AC32   0.276
2021-03-01   ABC        AD12   0.445

**end result**


date         account    id     value
2021-03-01   ABC        AM91   0.354
2021-03-01   ABC        AC32   0.276
2021-03-01   ABC        AD12   0.445
2021-03-01   DEF        AC32   0.276
2021-03-01   DEF        AD12   0.445
```

so the row with account ABC & id AM74 has been deleted

```
MERGE account_val t
USING #data s
ON t.date = #s.date and
t.account = #s.account and
t.id = #s.id
WHEN MATCHED
UPDATE t.value = s.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT(date, account, id, value)
VALUES(#s.date, #s.account, #s.id, #s.value)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use common table expression to select rows where account='ABC' to perform, insert, update and delete.

```
with cte as 
(
    select * from account_val where ACCOUNT='ABC'
)
MERGE cte t
USING #data s
ON t.date = #s.date and
t.account = #s.account and
t.id = #s.id
WHEN MATCHED
UPDATE t.value = s.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT(date, account, id, value)
VALUES(#s.date, #s.account, #s.id, #s.value)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE;
```